# xcode not recognizing NSPopUpButton as a class

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, nspopupbutton

I'm trying to implement an NSPopUpButton but Xcode does not recognize it. After I type NSPopUpButton Xcode does not offer code completion and reports the problem "use of undeclared identifier". Is there a specific framework I have to add and if so which one. Sorry I know there is probably a simple fix...

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That's because `NSPopUpButton` inherits from `NSButton` which is declared in the AppKit framework for OS X, and you can not use an OS X class in an iOS project.

(Basing this off the use of the iOS tag in the question)

If this is a Mac project, then you should check to make sure that your class is importing the AppKit framework, or `Cocoa/Cocoa.h` which also imports AppKit.

Comment: great that answers my question. Is there anyway to implement a pop up button in cocoa touch?

Comment: @rivtracks Great to hear! Be sure to mark this answer as correct if it solved the problem. And not exactly, the closest you'll get will probably be UITableView, or UIPickerView.